# Build OpenCV + CUDA + Contrib for Windows 10

Tags: python, opencv, cmake-gui

I am trying to use [cuda optical flow functions](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d3f/group__cudaoptflow.html) in OpenCV from Python. I have successfully built the OpenCV 4.5.2 with cuda and I added the `modules` folder in `opencv-contrib` in the `CMake`. When I want to call the optical flow functions, both for [cpu](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/df/dde/classcv_1_1DenseOpticalFlow.html) (e.g. [DualTVL1OpticalFlow](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/dc/d4d/classcv_1_1optflow_1_1DualTVL1OpticalFlow.html)) and [gpu](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d3f/group__cudaoptflow.html) (e.g. [OpticalFlowDual_TVL1](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d6/d39/classcv_1_1cuda_1_1OpticalFlowDual__TVL1.html)) from **Python** I get the following errors:

- CPU: `AttributeError: module "cv2" has not attribute optflow`
- GPU: `AttributeError: module "cv2" has not attribute cuda_NvidiaOpticalFlow_1_0`

I am pretty sure it has something to do with the building because when I build opencv using `pip install opencv-python` and `pip install opencv-contrib-python` I can use the cpu functions but **I want to access gpu functions from Python.** I use `cmake-gui` and I enable the following flags:

- `WITH_CUDA`  ☑
- `OPENCV_DNN_CUDA`  ☑
- `ENABLE_FAST_MATH`  ☑
- `OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES`  <path/to/contrib/modules>
- `ENABLE_CUDA_FAST_MAT`  ☑
- `CUDA_ARCH_BIN`  <my_GPU_arch>
- `BUILD_opencv_cudaoptflow`  ☑
- `BUILD_opencv_optflow`  ☑

I was wondering if someone that was able to call the cuda optical flow functions from Python can help with this issue. Thanks.

Comment: hi, perhaps we could work our way backwards...have you confirmed the version of opencv that you are using when you import is indeed the version that you compiled? 

import cv2 as cv
print( cv.__version__ )

Comment: Both of them are 4.5.2 @ShawnRamirez.